# limit terminal output buffer size

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

Is there a way to limit the amount of text that will be buffered by a terminal application, to be output to the display?

For example, if I were to call an application that writes 2,000,000 lines to stdout as fast as possible, the application may return quickly, but the terminal may spend several further minutes showing flickering walls of text before returning the idle prompt. Presumably those 2,000,000 lines of text have been buffered, and the terminal application is working it's way through the buffer, generating thousands of display updates. Is there a way to limit the buffer size, such that if there are more than e.g. 1,000 lines yet to be rendered, the oldest ones are just dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I were to call an application that writes 2,000,000 lines to stdout as fast as possible, the application may return quickly

That's not how it works.

Similarly to pipes, tty lines also have a relatively small buffer size. It looks to me that the kernel's buffer size for a terminal line is around 12 kB.

(How do I know it? I didn't want to study any existing source code, nor write a testing tool. So I fired up a terminal emulator, queried the tty line it's using (`tty` command, let's say it said `/dev/pts/5`), and froze it by sending a SIGSTOP. Then, from a different terminal, I sent some bytes to its terminal line using non-blocking write: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/pts/5 bs=65536 oflag=nonblock`.)

There might be several buffers connected to each other, e.g. if you're running `tmux` or alike then the data traverses through two tty lines as well as tmux's internal buffering, or if you work over `ssh` then the ssh server, the network, and the ssh client also add some buffer, but the overall buffer size you'll have is still magnitudes lower than the amount of data you're handling (which is around 100 MB, assuming 50 bytes per line on average).

Terminal emulators also read their input in similarly small chunks, e.g. around 4 - 8 kB.

(How do I know? I checked under `/proc/<terminal's pid>/fd` which file descriptor corresponds to the terminal line's master side `/dev/ptmx` and strace'd the terminal emulator looking for reads from this fd.)

When an application sends this much data to a process that reads it slowly, the application is often blocking on the write it performs. In other words, a slow reader results in the writer also running slowly (more precisely: regularly entering the "sleep" state, so that the kernel can run some other process instead, until the terminal consumes some of the data and the process can write to the tty line again).

To see it for yourself: Start a `cat largefile` that takes a minute or so. In another terminal locate `cat`'s PID (e.g. `pidof cat`), let's say it's 12345. Then see which fd is connected to `cat`'s input file: `ls -l /proc/12345/fd`, locate the line belonging to `largefile`, most likely it'll be fd number 3. Now ask the file offset at which `cat` is at, reading its input file: `cat /proc/12345/fdinfo/3`. You'll notice that this offset grows pretty much linearly while the terminal is handling all this data; and `cat` will only quit a tad bit sooner than the visual terminal activity stops (this difference is probably not even measurable by manually executed commands).

---

> several further minutes

On my pretty average laptop, with a terminal emulator whose performance is quite okay (not the best out there, but not bad either), processing 100 MB of data takes about 10 seconds.

> thousands of display updates

Pretty much every graphical terminal emulator handles the input as quickly as it can without updating the display all the time (that would be unbearably slow), and sometimes (ideally 60 times per second, adjusted to the display's refresh rate) briefly stops processing the input in order to update the display. Some terminal emulators keep this refresh rate, some adaptively skip frames if there's a continous input stream to process. My one refreshes the display around 25 times per second, that is, around 250 times during the processing of a 100 MB stream.

You either have a poorly performing computer or a poorly performing terminal emulator, or have exaggerated, or your data is even much bigger.

---

> Is there a way to limit the buffer size, such that if there are more than e.g. 1,000 lines yet to be rendered, the oldest ones are just dropped?

Terminals don't have such a feature.

First, they'd need a much bigger input buffer, in order to determine if they could do such skipping. A large input buffer would probably mean unnecessary display update delays under normal operation.

Second, your scrollback buffer would be broken, you wouldn't be able to scroll back to see previous output.

Third, even the current state could be broken, e.g. if it misses escape sequences that altered the color or something like that.

No, this would be an utter misfeature. Terminal emulators have to process all the data they receive.

---

So, what can you do if there's a process running that prints so much data that you have to wait for that for minutes?

You can interrupt that process using `Ctrl+C` (SIGINT), or if that does not work, you can try the typically more agressive `Ctrl+\` (SIGQUIT). Remember that the producer application is almost certainly still running and is yet to print those data -- unless you abort it.

You can switch to a different terminal emulator tab or a different application, do whatever you want to do there, and come back to this terminal later.

You can take a brief break, stretch, stare at some distant point for a few seconds, it does good.

You can pick your preferred terminal emulator based on how quickly it handles enormous amount of data.

If your workflow regularly involves sending this much data to your terminal then rework your workflow. For example, pipe the given app's output through `tail`, which, obviously, can process the data much more quickly than a terminal emulator could (it has significantly less things to do with that data).

Sending 100 MB of data (2 million lines) to the terminal shouldn't be part of your regular workflow. You as a human being won't be able to skim through it, let alone properly process it, so then what's point? 2M lines sent to the terminal is not data, it's junk. It should only happen accidentally and rarely enough so that having to wait for it, or having to terminate the application and restart it with significantly lower verbosity, should not be an issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, I actually just got back from a 2-week vacation! And thanks for the extensive response, I learned a lot! (well, some, admittedly some bits were over my head...).
I did simplify the situation - perhaps I shouldn't have done. IRL i'm using a kindle as a display, going via ssh and tmux. The slow update time on the kindle display is why performance is so bad, and why such a thing is necessary. I expected this may complicate matters, but didn't wish to make the question overly complex. I do see why such a feature doesn't exist, in hindsight it makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps this changes things a lot though - since the application does not need to wait for the kindle to be ready for input - i can see the application finish on the desktop, but the kindle continues to update for some time; the buffer must be associated with ssh/tmux.

Comment: I think ultimately the only way for me to achieve what I'm looking for is going to be writing my own application to limit the throughput rate, and pipe the output from my application through that. I was hoping to avoid the need to do that, since it increases typing on every command and/or requires me to remember to pipe as necessary every time its required.

Comment: lastly as for why this is necessary, unfortunately there are situations in which you are running an application that is excessively verbose but you do not have control over it, or for example in debugging where turning up the verbosity so that you can look at the output just prior to a crash is the quickest thing to do. I agree it's a blunt tool, and more controlled output would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for giving a broader context! I'm not familiar with Kindle as a hardware (I guess it's indeed notably slower than typical computers) or as a book reader, let alone as an ssh client. Anyway, a decent ssh client should not spend too much time updating its display so that it can hardly process the input; quite the opposite, as long as it has input to handle, that should be its primary focus. As for your use case, e.g. seeing the end of the debug output, I do see your point, still, it's a good idea to lift off some load from the terminal, e.g. redirect to a file and view it with `less`.